# Expectation involving a maximum of a sequence of i.i.d. Gaussians

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, limits, normal-distribution, expectation

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be a sequence of i.i.d. standard Gaussian random variables.  Denote the maximum of this sequence by $M_n$.  I am interested in evaluating the following expectation:

$$\tag{1}\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-f(n)\sqrt{\log n}M_n}\right]$$

when $n$ is large for $f(n)$ satisfying $f(n)=\omega(1/\log\log n)$ and $f(n)=o(1)$.  My best guess is that if this expectation exists, it tends to $n^{-f(n)}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, since I can show (see below) that this holds for $f(n)=o(1/\log\log n)$.  Of course, my problem would be solved if there existed an (asymptotic) expression for the moment generating function of $M_n$, but I am not aware of such.  [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89030/expectation-of-the-maximum-of-gaussian-random-variables) seems to be related and maybe indicative on how hard this problem is.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**What I did**

Using the techniques in my answer to my [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557686/convergence-of-a-sequence-involving-the-maximum-of-i-i-d-gaussian-random-variab), one can show that $P\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(n)\log n\left(\frac{M_n}{\sqrt{2\log n}}-1\right)=0\right)=1$ when $f(n)=o(1/\log\log n)$, as $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ are both zero in that case.  Arithmetic manipulation of $(1)$ then yields the asymptotic form $n^{-f(n)}$.

**Another remark**

An answer by Shai Covo to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24743/does-exceptionalism-persist-as-sample-size-gets-large) contains the reference to [this paper](http://gupea.ub.gu.se/bitstream/2077/3092/1/correction.pdf).  Using the equation for the asymptotic approximation of the $i^{\text{th}}$ order statistic found in this paper and used in the answer, we can write the following:

$$\tag{2}M_n\approx\sqrt{2\log n}-\frac{\log(\log(n))+\log(4\pi)-2W}{2\sqrt{2\log n}}$$

where $W$ is a random variable that has the density $f_W(w)=\exp[-w-\exp(-w)]$,  $-\infty <w<\infty$.

Now, I am not sure whether $(2)$ can be used to obtain the asymptotic approximation to moment generating function of $M_n$.  If we do, using Mathematica, we obtain the following:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}\mathbb{E}[e^{tM_n}]&\approx&\exp\left[t\left(\sqrt{2\log n}-\frac{\log(\log(n))+\log(4\pi)}{2\sqrt{2\log n}}\right)\right]\times\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left[-w\left(1-\frac{t}{\sqrt{2\log n}}\right)-\exp(-w)\right]dw\\
&=&\exp\left[t\left(\sqrt{2\log n}-\frac{\log(\log(n))+\log(4\pi)}{2\sqrt{2\log n}}\right)\right]\Gamma\left[1-\frac{t}{\sqrt{2\log n}}\right]
\end{array}$$
valid for $t<1$.  Plugging in $t=-f(n)\sqrt{\log n}$, dropping low order terms, and absorbing the constants into $f(n)$, I get:

$$\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-f(n)\sqrt{\log n}M_n}\right]\approx n^{-f(n)}(\log n)^{f(n)}\Gamma[1+f(n)]$$

However, I am not sure if this usage of $(2)$ is kosher...